# PHP File As JSON Data File for security reasons

Tags: php, json

I have a question:
How safe to use PHP file JSON data file.
I am storing some data in a JSON file. Although the data is not really sensitive, I still like to prevent unauthorized access. So I did code something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$token=$_SESSION['Salt'].$_SESSION['jSalt'];
$token=md5($token);
if($token==$_SESSION['token'])
{

?>
[{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Item 0",
  "price": "2169"
 },
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Item 1",
  "price": "1051"
 },
....
```

The code is working and my table is using PHP file as data source but I don't know if this is proper way doing it.

The $_SESSION['Salt'] is user spesific and $_SESSION['jSalt'] is session spesific and doing the same calculation (to calculate $_SESSION['token']) in the page that using the file as Data Source.

Is this proper way to secure or you may suggest some other ways?

Thnx in advance